# Css layout in modern webdesign

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm pretty horrified by css since it was born.
Anyway, I'm trying to understand a functional way of doing a modern css layout.

Let's say a site with a top menu, a left floated menu, a right floated news feed and a center content.

I've tried with this:

```css
.leftcontent {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
.rightcontent {
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  background-color:aqua;
}
.centercontent {
  height:100%;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="leftcontent">
    <p>
      Well, you can tell by the way I use my walk
      I'm a woman's man, no time to talk
      Music loud and women warm, I've been kicked around
      Since I was born
      And now it's alright, it's okay
      And you may look the other way
      We can try to understand
      The New York Times' effect on man
      Whether you're a brother or whether you're a mother
      You're stayin' alive, stayin' alive
      Feel the city breakin' and everybody shakin'
      And we're stayin' alive, stayin' alive
      Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive, stayin' alive
      Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive
      Well now, I get low and I get high
      And if I can't get either, I really try
      Got the wings of heaven on my shoes
      I'm a dancin' man and I just can't lose
      You know it's alright, it's okay
      I'll live to see another day
      We can try to understand
      The New…
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="centercontent">
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Let me open up the discussion with 
    I'm not impressed 
    With any mother fucking word I say
    See I lied that I cried
    When he came inside
    And now I'm burning a highway Hades
    Shut the fuck up
    When I'm trying to think
    I gotta keep my concentration 
    Give me one more drink
    And then I'll try to remember all the advice 
    That my good book told me
    And all the lost souls say
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Or get me out of the sun
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Someone get me out of the sun
    Drugs, bars, backseats of cars blowing boys
    What a boring life I've led so far
    Just a prime thirteen 
    When I…
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Let me open up the discussion with 
    I'm not impressed 
    With any mother fucking word I say
    See I lied that I cried
    When he came inside
    And now I'm burning a highway Hades
    Shut the fuck up
    When I'm trying to think
    I gotta keep my concentration 
    Give me one more drink
    And then I'll try to remember all the advice 
    That my good book told me
    And all the lost souls say
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Or get me out of the sun
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Someone get me out of the sun
    Drugs, bars, backseats of cars blowing boys
    What a boring life I've led so far
    Just a prime thirteen 
    When I…Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Let me open up the discussion with 
    I'm not impressed 
    With any mother fucking word I say
    See I lied that I cried
    When he came inside
    And now I'm burning a highway Hades
    Shut the fuck up
    When I'm trying to think
    I gotta keep my concentration 
    Give me one more drink
    And then I'll try to remember all the advice 
    That my good book told me
    And all the lost souls say
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Or get me out of the sun
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Someone get me out of the sun
    Drugs, bars, backseats of cars blowing boys
    What a boring life I've led so far
    Just a prime thirteen 
    When I…
  </div>
  <div class="rightcontent">
    The only thing I ever wanted
    The only thing I ever needed
    Is my own way, I gotta have it all
    I don't want your opinion, I don't need your ideas
    Stay the fuck out of my face, stay away from me
    I am my own God, I do as I please
    Just wipe your own ass and shut your mouth
    I had enough and you're going down
    Shut your mouth
    What comes around you know goes around
    My mind is playing tricks on me
    I am not as stable as I used to be
    Pushed and shoved, you know you're going too far
    I will not break my back for you no more
    I am gonna go my way, I am gonna take control
    Time to wake up and dig myself out of this hell
    Just wipe your own ass and shut your mouth
    I had enough and you're going down
    Shut your…
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[not working, wow](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUW8JSQ0CTIY)

Well, I was disappointed. All floating explanations went down the drain.
I was expecting, well, a right and left floating div and a center content.

Or, what is the best way to do what I described? divs with inline (or inline-block) display? I can work also if you link examples

Someone can fix or give working examples?

Comment: I think this resource has what you're looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_website_layout.asp

Answer (score 0):

You may use `position: fixed` to have left and right menu floated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.leftcontent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:blue;
}
.rightcontent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color:aqua;
}
.centercontent {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="leftcontent">
    Well, you can tell by the way I use my walk
    I'm a woman's man, no time to talk
    Music loud and women warm, I've been kicked around
    Since I was born
    And now it's alright, it's okay
    And you may look the other way
    We can try to understand
    The New York Times' effect on man
    Whether you're a brother or whether you're a mother
    You're stayin' alive, stayin' alive
    Feel the city breakin' and everybody shakin'
    And we're stayin' alive, stayin' alive
    Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive, stayin' alive
    Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive
    Well now, I get low and I get high
    And if I can't get either, I really try
    Got the wings of heaven on my shoes
    I'm a dancin' man and I just can't lose
    You know it's alright, it's okay
    I'll live to see another day
    We can try to understand
    The New…
  </div>
  <div class="centercontent">
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Let me open up the discussion with 
    I'm not impressed 
    With any mother fucking word I say
    See I lied that I cried
    When he came inside
    And now I'm burning a highway Hades
    Shut the fuck up
    When I'm trying to think
    I gotta keep my concentration 
    Give me one more drink
    And then I'll try to remember all the advice 
    That my good book told me
    And all the lost souls say
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Or get me out of the sun
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Someone get me out of the sun
    Drugs, bars, backseats of cars blowing boys
    What a boring life I've led so far
    Just a prime thirteen 
    When I…
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Let me open up the discussion with 
    I'm not impressed 
    With any mother fucking word I say
    See I lied that I cried
    When he came inside
    And now I'm burning a highway Hades
    Shut the fuck up
    When I'm trying to think
    I gotta keep my concentration 
    Give me one more drink
    And then I'll try to remember all the advice 
    That my good book told me
    And all the lost souls say
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Or get me out of the sun
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Someone get me out of the sun
    Drugs, bars, backseats of cars blowing boys
    What a boring life I've led so far
    Just a prime thirteen 
    When I…Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    Let me open up the discussion with 
    I'm not impressed 
    With any mother fucking word I say
    See I lied that I cried
    When he came inside
    And now I'm burning a highway Hades
    Shut the fuck up
    When I'm trying to think
    I gotta keep my concentration 
    Give me one more drink
    And then I'll try to remember all the advice 
    That my good book told me
    And all the lost souls say
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Or get me out of the sun
    Every day I wake up
    Every day I wake up alone
    (Kill me just kill me)
    Someone get me out of the sun
    Drugs, bars, backseats of cars blowing boys
    What a boring life I've led so far
    Just a prime thirteen 
    When I…
  </div>
  <div class="rightcontent">
    The only thing I ever wanted
    The only thing I ever needed
    Is my own way, I gotta have it all
    I don't want your opinion, I don't need your ideas
    Stay the fuck out of my face, stay away from me
    I am my own God, I do as I please
    Just wipe your own ass and shut your mouth
    I had enough and you're going down
    Shut your mouth
    What comes around you know goes around
    My mind is playing tricks on me
    I am not as stable as I used to be
    Pushed and shoved, you know you're going too far
    I will not break my back for you no more
    I am gonna go my way, I am gonna take control
    Time to wake up and dig myself out of this hell
    Just wipe your own ass and shut your mouth
    I had enough and you're going down
    Shut your…
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is kindof modern and solves the problem with minimal css, just add this class:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
```

If you want to achieve that the content has a fixed position for scrolling, or other effect, mind reading this MDN [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Personally, to avoid building layout with pure CSS I recommend using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), as it comes with a lot of tools and templates that look really good and are easy to use.